# How to use ssl certificate in worklight

Tags: ssl, certificate, ibm-mobilefirst

I want use ssl certificate in worklight. Kindly suggest how to use. If ssl is used how the communication happens between mobile app and worklight server. What will happen if the certificate is expired.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to change on the client-side other than making sure that you set up the application to connect to the correct server address using the HTTP**S** protocol and correct secure port number, typically 443 but may be different depending on how you setup your server.

To setup the server with a certificate, review the following user documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_configuring_wl.html

There are topics for using self-signed certificates and using untrusted certificates; note that you did not mention anything on the particular setup you are attempting to accomplish, so... that's it.